# Printing gt table with rmarkdown::render not working

Tags: r, r-markdown, gt

I have this report.Rmd example below

````
---
title: "Report"
author: "Me"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d de %B de %Y')`"
output:
  html_document
---

## Test

```{r first,  echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)
print( mtcars %>% gt() )

```
````

it works fine in Knit with RStudio

but when I try to create it from an external file this way

rmarkdown::render('report.Rmd', output_file = paste0('report.html'))

It shows all the messages and outputs in the console and in view pane, generates de html file, but it does not print the gt table.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `print` function. `mtcars %>% gt()`

Comment: thank you, now I'm trying to do the same but inside a loop and sourcing an external R. I going to set a new question